# flutter:: \MainActivity.kt: (342, 87): Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types

Tags: flutter, dart

> \MainActivity.kt: (342, 87): Type inference failed. The value of the
> type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types,
> receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.

The above error occurred in the MainActivity file. How can I solve this?

MainActivity.kt

```
private fun updatePowers(bdata: ByteArray) {
    val data = byte2short(bdata)
    val sampleVal = data[data.size - 1]
    val escapeStatusList = arrayOf("paused", "stopped", "initialized", "unset")
    mAveragePower = if (sampleVal.toInt() == 0 || Arrays.asList(escapeStatusList).contains(mStatus)) {
        -120.0 // to match iOS silent case
    } else {
        // iOS factor : to match iOS power level
        val iOSFactor = 0.25
        20 * Math.log(Math.abs(sampleVal.toInt()) / 32768.0) * iOSFactor
    }
    mPeakPower = mAveragePower
    // Log.d(LOG_NAME, "Peak: " + mPeakPower + " average: "+ mAveragePower);
}
```